# Espresso: How to select one element from a list of elements

Tags: android, android-espresso

If I have multiple elements with the same id and other properties. How can I click only on the second element without performing an action on the first.

In Appium , I used to do the same with :

driver.findElements(By.id("id")).get(2).click();

Could you tell me the equivalent in Espresso?

Comment: Can you, maybe, google it yourself? I mean, before asking, you must search by yourself a little more, typing "stackoverflow.com" in google isn't enough....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onData(hasToString(startsWith("item_name")))
        .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.view_id)).atPosition(2)
        .perform(click());
```